# error met in plot two curves in one Figure (python-pandas-matplotlib)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I tried to plot two `DataFrame` curves in one figure using `pandas` and `matplotlib` in `Python`. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.hold()
df['open'].plot(color="green", linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-",label='open')
do = DataFrame(df[df['jiangjz']==True]['open'])
do.plot(marker='o',linestyle=".") 
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xticklabels(df.index)
plt.show()
```

The simple data structure of `df['open']` and `do` is:

```
df:              open       do(one data):        open
     index                         index   
     2014-10-18   11               2014-12-10    12
     2014-12-10   12
     2015-12-10   12
```

the `df` plotted is a curve and `do` is a point. If I removed the `hold()` line and the `axes` two line, it produces one figure, but the `x-lim` starts with day `2014-12-10` rather than `2014-10-18`. I reset the `x-lim` of the `do` to meet the `df`, but the result becomes two figure. `hold()` line does not seems to work.

Comment: Why don't you make a list of dataframes and plot in a loop

Comment: uh..i had learned python only 1 weeks.following the ansers bellow with a loop,it really works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try plotting from within a list

```
from itertools import izip

import pylab as plt
import pandas

d1 = pandas.DataFrame( {'open': pandas.np.random.random(100)} )
d2 = pandas.DataFrame( {'open': pandas.np.random.random(100)} )
my_dfs = [d1, d2] # or in your case [ df,do]
my_opts = [ {"color":"green", "linewidth":1.0, "linestyle":"-","label":"open"},
            {"marker":"o","linestyle":"."} ]
for d,opt in izip(my_dfs, my_opts):
    d['open'].plot( **opt)
plt.legend()
```

This yields the figure 
[image]